# ReferenceError: Can't find variable - Qunit Testing with ember in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

So I have the following files:

app/assets/javascripts/aisis_planner.js

```
//= require handlebars
//= require ember
//= require ember-data
//= require_self
//= require ./store
//= require_tree ./models
//= require_tree ./controllers
//= require_tree ./views
//= require_tree ./helpers
//= require_tree ./components
//= require_tree ./templates
//= require_tree ./routes
//= require ./router

window.AisisPlanner = Ember.Application.create();
```

Then under tests/javascripts/test_helper.js

```
//= require application
//= require_tree .
//= require_self
//= require aisis_planner

document.write('<div id="ember-testing-container"><div id="ember-testing"></div></div>');
document.write('<style>#ember-testing-container { position: absolute; background: white; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 640px; height: 384px; overflow: auto; z-index: 9999; border: 1px solid #ccc; } #ember-testing { zoom: 50%; }</style>');

AisisPlanner.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
AisisPlanner.setupForTesting();
AisisPlanner.injectTestHelpers();

function exists(selector) {
  return !!find(selector).length;
}
```

But I keep getting the error, when going to `localhost:3000/qunit`:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: AisisPlanner
```

Whats going on? My app loads fine, for non testing, but when it comes to setting it up for testing I get these errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a js file is getting inserted out of order. (such as tests/javascripts/test_helper.js before app/assets/javascripts/aisis_planner.js)

Comment: This answer doesn't help me

Comment: Why doesn't it help you?  It's the answer.  If you want me to hunt down which js file it is, you can host your site send me the link and I'll do it for you.